# how to load whole view(with styles and scripts) in bootstrap modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I want to load one page into another(I'm working in laravel ). I have form on page, when user clicks on button bootstrap popup modal is shown. so i need to load whole page (include scripts and styles) in this bootstrap popup modal. the problem is my loaded page in popup, doesn't work correctly(i guess because of scripts. main page has bootstrap, jQuery and so on, and my popup view also has jQuery and bootstrap, and some other scripts, so as I see it loads these scripts two times). This is how console looks after my loaded page is poped out
[image]

I use laravel unisharp file manager [github](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager)

here's my edit button

```
<a class="few_edits btn green default edit-vid-btn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-vid">Edit video</a>
```

my js

```
$(function(){
        $(".edit-vid-btn").on('click', function(){

            //window.open('/laravel-filemanager/?type=Files', 'File Manager',"width=700,height=500");

            /*$.ajax({
                url: "/laravel-filemanager/?type=Files",
                type: 'get',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.modal-video-cont').append(data);
                }
            })*/

            $('.modal-video-cont').load('/laravel-filemanager/?type=Files');

        });
    });
```

is there way to fix it?

Comment: yes you can either use a iframe or place the js on the page and only load the html

Comment: thanks for reply. yes, i see, after googling im trying it with iframe

Comment: why not remove the js and css files from the filemanger page? then if you load just the html it should work fine.

Comment: Why don't you try to include that JS in main page only from where that  modal is going to be opened.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem, just append your loaded data in iframe. that's it)

Comment: Have you tried giving every external file full path rather then relative path?? like `<script src="https://mywebsite.com/js/d3.v4.min.js"></script>` rather then just `<script src="js/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`